# What is specific about the pre-ordination of these 3 things - spouses, houses, and fields?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, talmud-bavli, tractate-sotah

Gemara Sotah 2a

אמר רב יהודה אמר רב ארבעים יום קודם יצירת הולד בת קול יוצאת ואומרת **בת פלוני לפלוני בית פלוני לפלוני שדה פלוני לפלוני...**

Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: Forty days before an embryo is formed a Divine Voice issues forth and says: ***The daughter of so-and-so is destined to marry so-and-so; such and such a house is destined to be inhabited by so-and-so; such and such a field is destined to be farmed by so-and-so***.

What is specific about the pre-ordination of these 3 things (spouses, houses, and fields)? Are other things less preordained? If so in what way are these three different?

Comment: Excellent question. Is this usually held to refer just to first homes (as the "daughter of so-and-so" generally is held to refer to first wives) or even to subsequent homes that have perhaps not even been built yet?

Comment: >>the "daughter of so-and-so" generally is held to refer to first wives - This is not just "generally held" . the Gemara right after that says clearly that it refers to Zivug Rishon (first match) and not to Zivug Shainy. The gemara does not say so about the other 2.

Comment: In אוצר ידיעות from (ר' יחיאל מיכל שטרן  (חלק א' פרק ס"ג he connects them to the three things that exempt a person from the army, that teach us what order to follow, house, vineyard, marriage.

הקשר בין שלשתם - בת, בית, שדה - הוא עפ"י מה שמבואר בסוטה (מד.). תנו רבנן אשר בנה אשר נטע אשר ארש לימדה תורה דרך ארץ, שיבנה אדם בית, ויטע כרם, ואח"כ ישא אשה ע"כ. וזהו הקשר בת פלוני כנגד אשר ארש, בית פלוני כנגד אשר בנה, שדה פלוני ננגד אשר נטע

Comment: @user17260  Thank you for sharing this. I wasn't looking for a connection, I'm looking for an explanation for what is specific about these 3 things in regard to preordaination, (is that a word??)  that the Gemara lists just them.

Comment: @ RibbisRabbiAndMore - Do you know of other milestones as important as marriage, employment and housing?

Comment: @user17260 what does milestones have to do with preordination?

Comment: While HaShem sees and knows all and is intimately involved in our lives as human beings, "Such-and-such head of lettuce" being ordained while Schlomo is still in the womb in 1974 for the side salad for the kosher meal on his flight to London on June 9th, 2021, though well within HaShem's power, is not necessarily subject to the same preordination as his wife, home, or job.

Comment: @JoshK Can you explain what you mean by "subject to the same preordination as..."

Comment: Let's call it a "level of preordination", @RibbisRabbiAndMore. I am positing that major life milestones, as per this very portion of the Gamarra, are subject to a higher level of attention to detail than minor details in life.

Comment: @JoshK And what is/are the difference/es between standard level and "higher level attention"? - (did you mean attention or preordaination?)

Comment: I would argue the very posukim you cited above are indicative of such difference.....these three things are destined 40 days before an embryo is formed i.e. other things are not

Comment: I've edited to change the word 'daughter' to 'wife' as I think that's a less ambiguous way of wording it. The gemara is not saying that one's daughter is preordained, but that one's wife is. Feel free to roll-back the edit if you disagree.

Comment: @JoelK The gemara actualy says both things BAS PLONI - the DAUGHTER of so-and-so L'Ploni (will be the WIFE) of so-and-so. So there is preordaination both for whos daughter the man will marry and which man the daughter will marry. So you did not need to change it.

Comment: But the way it was phrased sounds like it's saying that the identity of one's own daughter is preordained. Do you want to change it to 'marriages', maybe?

Comment: @JoelK Why do you assume it to mean *identity*?, It is referring to the DESTINY of one's daughter, that is preordained.

Comment: One of the commentators on-the-spot (could be Rashi, but almost definately a Rishon) connects all three directly to marriage. Of course, it's still unclear why marriage, and what "levels of predestination" actually means...

Comment: I was at a wedding recently where the Chosson's Rosh Yeshiva spoke about this, and suggested that it's because all of these are created by Hashem just to serve man. Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות for a "drasha" at a wedding its ok. But realistically speaking, isn't EVERYTHING created by Hashem just to serve man??

Answer (score 1):

Kabbalicly wise this refers to 3 types of one's Neshomah's "garments":

1. The first level - One's body incl. one's wife, as we hold that אשתו כגופו.
2. One's House and "immediate" belongings
3. One's distant property such as real estate.

The division is not so consistent thru different Halachic issues, such as נגעים for example or דיני ממונות, but nevertheless, it exists.

Comment: 1- How is that kabalic? Nothing you said is kabalistic. 2- So I ask, do you mean to say that theese are exampples of the 3 garments, and anything having to do with the body is included in the first, health etc. and anything to do with "immediate" belongings are included in the second, car etc. and all other property is included in the 3rd? If sdo then just say that everything is preordained. If these 3 are specific and not just examples, then why not other things on the same levels?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore 1. B"H, I'm relieved, I worried I might have said some secrets. 2. Yes, this is like your money (called דמים) which is a part of you, you just don't feel it (oh, maybe you do, but still). 3. When three or more things are listed (wither in Gemmorah or TANAKH), the K. approach (I generalize greatly) explains it necessarily on different levels or ספירות or against the 4 letter name etc.